# Vue.js 2 components parent child item not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to vue and I am getting the error `referenceError: items is not defined`. Can anyone see why this happens or give me some pointers?

I think it has something to do with the `items` not being set on first look at the template.

**My code**:

```
<div id="root">
    <task-list></task-list>
    <template id="my-parent">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>id</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr is="task" v-for="item in items" :item="item"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </template>

    <template id="my-child">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>

</div>
<script>



Vue.component('task-list', {
 template: '#my-parent',
 data: function() {
        return {
            items: []
        }
  },
  methods: {
    getMyData: function(val) {

        var _this = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'vuejson.php',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                _this.items = data;
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }  
        })

     }
  },
  mounted: function () {
       this.getMyData("0");
    }
});

Vue.component('task', {

  template: '#my-child',
  props: ['item'],

    data: function() {
        return {
            item: {}
        }
    }
});
new Vue({
  el: "#root",

});

</script>
```

Comment: I guess you deleted a link (url, image?) to your code since no code is visible. Instead of fixing the link, just write the code as plain ASCII.

Comment: sorry first time using stackoverflow

Comment: updated now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working modified code:

```
<template id="my-child">
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
<template id="my-parent">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>id</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr is="task" v-for="item in items" :item="item"></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
<div id="root">
    <task-list></task-list>
</div>
```

And js:

```
Vue.component('task-list', {
  template: '#my-parent',
  data: function() {
    return {
        items: []
    }
},
methods: {
getMyData: function(val) {

    var _this = this;
    _this.items = [{name: '1.name', id: 1}];
 }
 },
 mounted: function () {
   this.getMyData("0");
}
});

Vue.component('task', {

template: '#my-child',
props: ['item'],

data: function() {
    return {
    }
}
});
new Vue({
el: "#root",

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bwuga3a5/)

It would be much easier to you to work with vue, if you do some tutorials first:)

edit: 
And one more thing: if you declare property(item in your case), dont use that name in data.
So, what I did:
- placed templates outside of your root element
- removed "item" from data

Comment: Great that makes perfect sense. Is the data function in the child not needed at all?

Comment: @Jim Phillips yea, You can ignore data function in task component.

Answer (score 1):

You should describe templates outside div#root. 
Example

```
<div id="root">
    <task-list></task-list>
</div>
 <template id="my-parent">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>id</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr is="task" v-for="item in items" :item="item"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </template>

    <template id="my-child">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
```

Because if they are in #root they are part of vue instance for it, and there is no **items** in it.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  //no items
});
```

Comment: Great, that explains it well